Groovy catch inner group in nested regex expression
For some context: I have a big file. File contain some data that I want to capture. I know said data follow a specific format. In my current case, I have 3, so I made three different regex to catch them:
def pattern1 = ~/arg1:\s([\w\s\.\-\:]+)/
def pattern2 = ~/arg2\s\-\s([\w\s\.\-\:]+)/
def pattern3 = ~/arg3="([\w\s\.\-\:]+)"/

Now, I want to catch those and process the data. For my previous files I could always manage to use only one regex, because the format was the same, only the argument name was different, so there was no problem, the code was something like that:
def pattern = ~/\s*([\w\s\_]+)\s*="\s*([\w\s\.\-\:\_\/=]+)\s*"/
(data.value =~ pattern).each { match ->
    def argName= match[1]
    def value = match[2]
    switch (argName) {
      case "arg1":
        newValue=transformArg1(value)
      case "arg2":
        newValue=transformArg2(value)
      case "arg3":
        newValue=transformArg3(value)
    }
}

Simple enough (note that data.value contains my file data). But now that I have multiple regex, I can't manage to get the value I want. Note that for this particular case, I don't care what the argument name is, the same process will be applied to the value; the argName is just usefull to find the value in the file. So my current code is like that:
def pattern1 = ~/arg1:\s([\w\s\.\-\:]+)/
def pattern2 = ~/arg2\s\-\s([\w\s\.\-\:]+)/
def pattern3 = ~/arg3="([\w\s\.\-\:]+)"/
def globalPattern = ~/(${pattern1}|${pattern2}|${pattern3})/

(data.value =~ globalPattern).each { match ->
  def value= match[1]
    newValue =  transformArg(value)
}

BUT, since globalPattern contains a group, match[1] contains the whole match. Not the inner group contained in the matchin pattern.
For exemple, if my file contain a line
exemple line containing interesting data arg1: data_to_capture, then the first pattern will match, and match[1] will contain the whole match, arg1: data_to_capture, instead of only the group defined in pattern1 which is only data_to_capture.
I've tried match[2], but I got an out of range (makes sense, globalPattern contains only one group, the other group is an "inner" group). I've tried match[1][1]. ChatGPT suggested match[1][0][1]. I've spent hours searching for groovy doc on the matter and trying different syntaxes but none worked.
I realize I could make one pattern like that:
def pattern= ~/[arg1|arg2|arg3][:=\s"]+([\w\s\.\-\:]+)/
But I'm afraid it may catch too much. Like, maybe I could have some lines in my files as exemple problematic line arg1="data_to_be_left_alone", and it would be caught by the pattern when I don't want it. The chances are slim but it's still a possibility, I'd rather stick to my three precises regexes...if anyone has a solution.

Please provide
a MRE

Seriously @cfrick? I provided the minimal code snippet with two example lines, one that should match and one that should not, and expected result with the one that should match. How is that not a MRE??

("exemple line containing interesting data arg1: data_to_capture" =~ globalPattern).each { match -> println match[2]  gives the expected result (and not an out-of-bounds-error). So, yes, seriously, provide a MRE.  And make it code instead of sprinkling the nuances over a nine paragraph essay.

alright, I should have used an example line with patterns 2 or 3 instead of 1, my bad. But honestly, I spent quite some time reducing that to a minimal reproducible example, only to have you commenting "produce a MRE" just because you don't wanna go through the hassle of copy-pasting the code snippet and writing other examples for the two others snippets, it's quite infuriating. If you don't wanna do it, don't, but I gave every necessary information to reproduce easily with a minimal amount of code and data, so there is a MRE. You don't like to read is your problem.

def r1 = /a=(\d+)/
def r2 = /b:(\d+)/
def r3 = /c@(\d+)/

def rx = ~"($r1|$r2|$r3)"

data = " sdfg a=11 fge124 b:22 c@33 a=444 ---"

(data=~rx).each{
  //drop first 2 items (whole match and first group) 
  //and find not null over other groups
  println it.drop(2).find() 
}

result:
11
22
33
444


why need to drop 2 elements?
in a global pattern the capturing groups and corresponding indexes in result
   ..(.(.).(.).(.).)..
0  |-----------------|    whole match - rx
1    (-------------)      first group declared in rx
2      (-)                second group (r1)
3          (-)                          r2
4              (-)                      r3


Works perfectly and with only little changes, thank you! I still have a hard time understanding why, if the solution is to drop the first 2 items, match[2] wouldn't contain the one I want. But I've tested it with both your code and mine, and turns out match[2] will sometimes be null, and sometimes be the same as it.drop(2).find(), no idea why yet.

So, I had to work again on the subject with something a tad more complicated: I needed two differents groups in each pattern.
Which mean I had to understand how thoses matches work, because the drop().find() method proposed as an answer wasn't working anymore. So I made another MRE:
data='{"id": "100", "name" = "monitor",price>125},{"id": "101", "name" = "usb wire",price>10}'

def pattern1 = ~/"(id)":\s"([\d]+)"/
def pattern2 = ~/"(name)"\s=\s"([\w\.\-\s]+)"/
def pattern3 = ~/(price)>([\d]+)/

def globalPattern = ~/${pattern1}|${pattern2}|${pattern3}/

(data =~ globalPattern).each { match ->
    println match
    println match.drop(1)
    def Element = match.drop(1).find()
    println "element:" + Element
}

And the result of that is:
["id": "100", id, 100, null, null, null, null]
[id, 100, null, null, null, null]
element:id
["name" = "monitor", null, null, name, monitor, null, null]
[null, null, name, monitor, null, null]
element:name
[price>125, null, null, null, null, price, 125]
[null, null, null, null, price, 125]
element:price
["id": "101", id, 101, null, null, null, null]
[id, 101, null, null, null, null]
element:id
["name" = "usb wire", null, null, name, usb wire, null, null]
[null, null, name, usb wire, null, null]
element:name
[price>10, null, null, null, null, price, 10]
[null, null, null, null, price, 10]
element:price

which means that, as @dagett said, the first element in match is the whole match. Second is first group, third is second group, etc... but there is no notion of "group in a group". If I define my global pattern like that:
def globalPattern = ~/(${pattern1}|${pattern2}|${pattern3})/
(ie with all patterns in one big group), the only difference is that my match variable will contain the whole match twice: once for the whole match, and another time for the first group (first group beeing all patterns, so the whole match again). The groups of pattern1 are not considered to be inside the first group; they just follow in the list
Then, and that's the interesting part, every group comes in order. So first group of pattern1, second group of pattern1, first group of pattern2, and so on. Obviously, the groups of the non-matching patterns are empty, thus the value null.
And that explain the problem I had when trying to access them with match[2]. If the match was not on the first pattern, then match[2] would be null, whereas the find() method simply takes the first non-null value.
Knowing that, the only thing left to do is just to remove the null elements from my match variable, and I'll have all the groups I need. findAll() does the job, and I still drop the first item since it's the full match and I'm not interested in it.
Which leads to:
data='{"id": "100", "name" = "monitor",price>125},{"id": "101", "name" = "usb wire",price>10}'

def pattern1 = ~/"(id)":\s"([\d]+)"/
def pattern2 = ~/"(name)"\s=\s"([\w\.\-\s]+)"/
def pattern3 = ~/(price)>([\d]+)/

def globalPattern = ~/${pattern1}|${pattern2}|${pattern3}/

(data =~ globalPattern).each { match ->
    def Element = match.drop(1).findAll()
    def ElementName = Element[0]
    def ElementValue = Element[1]
    println "name: " + ElementName
    println "value: " + ElementValue
}

With result:
name: id
value: 100
name: name
value: monitor
name: price
value: 125
name: id
value: 101
name: name
value: usb wire
name: price
value: 10

I don't know if it would help anyone out there, but I'm happy enough to have understood it :)
